# linear recurrence relation with inhomogeneous trigonometric term

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

Find the explicit sequence that satisfy:

$$ x_{n+2}-3x_{n+1}+2x_n= \cos^2(\frac{\pi}{2}n)\sin(\frac{\pi}{6}n)$$

and the initial condition
$$x_0=x_1=0$$

My first attempt was to compute some term and guess the law:  $x_2=x_3=0$

$x_4=\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$

$x_5=3\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$

$x_6=4\sqrt3$

$x_7=9\sqrt3$

$x_8=19\sqrt3$

$x_9=39\sqrt3$

$x_{10}=\frac{391}{2}\sqrt3$

then i try to follow the wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_non-homogeneous_linear_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients

but i don't know the form of the inhomogeneous solution.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: i compute some of the first term to find a law, but nothing...
then i tried variation of parameter but the integral becomes ugly (there must be another easiest method)

Comment: Please include your attempt in your question.  Otherwise, your question is in danger of being closed due to missing context.

Comment: Do you know Z transforms?

Comment: no but thank you for the advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a linear difference equation so the solution can be written as

$$
x_n = x^h_n + x^p_n \\
x^h_{n+2}-3x^h_{n+1}+2x^h_n= 0\\
x^p_{n+2}-3x^p_{n+1}+2x^p_n= \cos^2(\frac{\pi}{2}n)\sin(\frac{\pi}{6}n)
$$

the difficult part is to obtain $x^p_n$ so we will focus that. Making

$$
x^p_n = a e^{\frac{i \pi  n}{3}}+b e^{-\frac{1}{3} i \pi  n}+c e^{\frac{2 i \pi  n}{3}}+d e^{-\frac{2}{3} i \pi  n}
$$

after substituting and grouping terms we get at

$$
\frac{1}{4} e^{-\frac{2}{3} i \pi  n} \left(-i \left(4 \sqrt{3} a+1\right) e^{i \pi  n}+i \left(4 \sqrt{3} b+1\right) e^{\frac{i \pi 
   n}{3}}+\left(-8 i \sqrt{3} c+12 c+i\right) e^{\frac{4 i \pi  n}{3}}+4 \left(3+2 i \sqrt{3}\right) d-i\right) = 0
$$

and then solving

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
 4 \left(3+2 i \sqrt{3}\right) d-i&=&0 \\
 4 \sqrt{3} b+1&=&0 \\
 4 \sqrt{3} a+1&=&0 \\
 -8 i \sqrt{3} c+12 c+i&=&0 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

we obtain

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
 a&=&-\frac{1}{4 \sqrt{3}} \\
 b&=&-\frac{1}{4 \sqrt{3}} \\
 c&=&\frac{1}{336} \left(-12 i+8 \sqrt{3}\right) \\
 d&=&\frac{1}{336} \left(12 i+8 \sqrt{3}\right) \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Comment: @polbos Here $x^p_n$ represents a particular solution to the complete recurrence equation.